Springcloud gateway route Predicate does not take effect
Background: I need to expect springcloud gateway to route to the specified interface according to the parameters in the post request. At present, I configure it according to the Predicate in springcloud gateway. I refer to ReadBodyPredicateFactory to customize a predicatefactory to meet our needs. I adjusted it many times according to the configuration, but it still did not take effect,
Can you help me find out where the configuration is wrong?
This is my config：
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: route1
          uri: http://host1:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/demo
            - name: MyReadBodyPredicateFactory 
              args:
                params: "23,22" 
        - id: route2
          uri: https://zplpreview.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/pdf-to-zpl
            - name: PdfPredicateFactory 
              args:
                params: "44,56" 


@Component()
@Slf4j
public class MyReadBodyPredicateFactory extends AbstractRoutePredicateFactory<MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config> {


    private static final List<HttpMessageReader<?>> messageReaders = HandlerStrategies
            .withDefaults().messageReaders();

    public MyReadBodyPredicateFactory() {
        super(MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config.class);
    }

    public MyReadBodyPredicateFactory(Class<MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config> configClass) {
        super(configClass);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> applyAsync(MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config config) {
        return new AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<Boolean> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
                Object cachedBody = exchange.getAttribute(MyFacadeConstants.CACHE_REQUEST_BODY_OBJECT_KEY);
                if (cachedBody != null) {
                    try {
                        boolean test = match(config.sceneIds, (MycRequest) cachedBody);
                        return Mono.just(test);
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            log.debug("Predicate test failed because class in predicate "
                                    + "does not match the cached body object", e);
                        }
                    }
                    return Mono.just(false);
                } else {
                    return ServerWebExchangeUtils.cacheRequestBodyAndRequest(exchange,
                            (serverHttpRequest) -> ServerRequest.create(exchange.mutate().request(serverHttpRequest).build(), messageReaders)
                                    .bodyToMono(MycRequest.class)
                                    .doOnNext(objectValue -> exchange.getAttributes().put(MyFacadeConstants.CACHE_REQUEST_BODY_OBJECT_KEY,objectValue))
                                    .map(objectValue -> { return match(config.sceneIds, objectValue);}));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean match(String params, MycRequest mycRequest) {
        if("others".equals(params)){
            return true;
        }
        String[] paramArray = params.split(",");
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(paramArray, mycRequest.getRouteId)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Predicate<ServerWebExchange> apply(MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config config) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "MyReadBodyPredicateFactory is only async.");
    }

    public static class Config {

        private String params;

        public MyReadBodyPredicateFactory.Config setParams(params) {
            this.params = params;
            return this;
        }

        public String getParams() {
            return params;
        }
    }
}

I expect to route based on the post parameters。


id: route2
uri: https://zplpreview.com
predicates:
- Path=/api/pdf
- name: PdfPredicateFactory
args:
params: "44,56"

